# xampp problem when trying to start it from control panel

Tags: xampp

frequently i am getting a problem with xampp. when i start the xampp from the control panel there is an issue with msql port. Its not starting and automatically turning off with some error.

```
[mysql] Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. 
[mysql] This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
[mysql] improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method 
[mysql] Press the Logs button to view error logs and check 
[mysql] the Windows Event Viewer for more clues 
[mysql].
```

In the stack overflow itself i got the solution to rectify it.  But what is the reason of getting the error behind it

Reason for occuring the problem and how to reinstall xampp without losing the data

Comment: Are you using Run as Administrator?

Answer (score 0):

Enter the Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features, uninstall any Mysql and xampp, then install xampp.